# Defining a new \Vec command to use with the esvect package

Tags: packages, vector, renewcommand

The `esvect` package uses the command `\vv{v}` to write an arrowhead above the letter in its argument (i.e., a vector), and the command `\vv*{v}{n}` to write a vector v with a subscript n. I would like to define a function `\Vec` so that `\Vec{v}` gives me `\vv*{v}{}`, while `\Vec{v}_n` gives `\vv*{v}{n}`.

In effect, I would like to use the `esvect` package in the same way as I would use the ordinary `\vec` command. Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `e` (embellishment) argument specifier for `\NewDocumentCommand`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{esvect}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Vec}{me{_}}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}{\vv{#1}}{\vv*{#1}{#2}}%
}

\begin{document}

With the standard \verb|\vv|
\[
\vv{v}+\vv*{v}{n}
\]

With the new \verb|\Vec|
\[
\Vec{v}+\Vec{v}_n
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Even better, you can avoid the small hole that's left by `\vv*`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{esvect}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\Vec}{me{_}}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}{\vv{#1}}{\vv*{#1}{\mspace{-2mu}#2}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\Vec{v}+\Vec{v}_n \\
\Vec{x}+\Vec{x}_n \\
\Vec{p}+\Vec{p}_n \\
\Vec{y}+\Vec{y}_n \\
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

Note that you need `\RenewDocumentCommand{\Vec}` if `amsmath` is loaded (with `amsmath`, `\Vec` is an alias for `\vec`).

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, that's what I was looking for!

Comment: @PolyPhys I added an improved version